# Disable animation based on screen size

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using waypoints.js for animations and I have got the following to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  "use strict"; 
    $('.slogan').waypoint(function(direction) {             
        $('.onelogo').toggleClass('hide', direction === 'down');
    });
});
```

But  the only problem with the above is that the animation still plays on mobile, so after reading I tried to implement the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function () {
        width=$(window).width();
        if (width > 950){
            var waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.slogan');
            for (var i = waypoints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                    element: waypoints[i],
                    handler: function(direction) {
                        this.element.classList.toggle('.hide');
                    },
                    offset: '60%',
                });
            }
        } else {
            // less then 950 px.
            if ($(".onelogo").hasClass(".hide")) {
                $(".onelogo").removeClass(".hide"); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But doing it that way the animation doesn't play at all

> html

```
<div class="slogan">        
        <img class="onelogo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

> css

```
.slogan {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 40%;
    line-height: 34px;
    color: #949494;
    z-index: 10;
}

.onelogo {
    display: block;
    height: 110px;
    width: auto;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}       

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -29vh;
}
```

Comment: Since your function is on resize, nothing will happen when you first load the page. I'm not familiar with waypoints.js, so I can't give too much specific advice, but the first thing to try would be adding a function to trigger a resize event at the very end of your function, after the resize function itself. Simply do `$(window).resize()` inside of `$(document).ready` to trigger the function you just did on page load.

Comment: Can you post your html/css too? possibly a fiddle?

Comment: Your above code has a syntax error in the Waypoint constructor. Remove the comma after the offset property. Also removeClass and toggle take a class name ("hide"), not a class selector (".name")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add the waypoint on `$(document).ready()`, and call the waypoint [enable](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/enable/) / [disable](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/disable/) based on the window size.

```
<script>
var waypoint;
function handleWayPoint() {
    var $width = $(window).width();
    console.log($width);
    if($width > 950) {
      waypoint[0].enable();
    }
    else {
        waypoint[0].disable();
    }
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  "use strict";
   waypoint= $('.slogan').waypoint(function(direction) {             
         $('.onelogo').toggleClass('hide', direction === 'down');
   });
   handleWayPoint();

   $(window).resize(function() {
      handleWayPoint();
   });
});
</script>
```

In addition to the errors I mentioned in my comments, the main issue with your other code is this line: `this.element.classList.toggle('.hide');` `this` in JavaScript works quite differently than it does in other languages (Java, C++ for example). In general, `this` in JavaScript is set to the object left of the dot operator (although there are exceptions). [This post goes into greater detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/8na3h455/25/)

Comment: I know how to use media queries but media queries are not going to do what I need the hide class does not hide it scrolls up and hides this dont show it at all

Comment: Well then can you post your html/css?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with waypoints, but you can try to wrap your logic in a function and then call it both on `$(document).ready` and `$(window).resize` :

```
function toggleAnimation(){
    width=$(window).width();

    if (width > 950){
    var waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.slogan');
        for (var i = waypoints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                element: waypoints[i],
                handler: function(direction) {
                    this.element.classList.toggle('.hide');
                },
                offset: '60%',
            });
         }
    } else {
       // less then 950 px.
       if ($(".onelogo").hasClass(".hide")) {
           $(".onelogo").removeClass(".hide"); 
       }

    }
}
```

and call...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    toggleAnimation();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        toggleAnimation();
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you like to stop the animation when the screen size is less than 950px?
I don't know, but I think that you can try this:

```
var waypoints = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        width=$(window).width();
        if (width > 950) {
            ...
        } else if (waypoints != null) {
            waypoints.disable() //or waypoints.destroy() if new instance
        }
    });
});
```